# Reading OUT ports for debugging

Tags: vhdl

I have a FIFO which has an interface that looks something like this:

```
entity fifo is
    port (
    CLK               : IN  std_logic := '0';
    DIN               : IN  std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
    ALMOST_EMPTY      : OUT std_logic;
    ALMOST_FULL       : OUT std_logic;
    DOUT              : OUT std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
    ...
    WR_ACK            : OUT std_logic
);
end fifo;
```

This interface is given, and I can't change iy. For debugging purposes, I want to see what is written and read to/from the FIFO. In other words, ideally I would like to assign two debug the in and out values of the FIFO, i.e.,

```
  DBG_FIFO_IN  <= DIN;
  DBG_FIFO_OUT <= DOUT;
```

For obvious reasons, the second assignment gives me the following error message:

> [exec] ERROR:HDLParsers:1401 - Object DOUT of mode OUT can not be
> read.

I am wondering if there is any way how I can assign the `DOUT` value to my debug symbol. The interface is given, so I can't make `DOUT` an inout signal.

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign the fifo output to a local signal you *can* read, then assign that signal to the output (or assign them both in parallel):

```
DBG_FIFO_OUT <= (your logic here);
DOUT         <= DBG_FIFO_OUT;
```

or

```
DBG_FIFO_OUT <= (your logic here);
DOUT         <= (your logic here);
```

Comment: Careful using the first option inside a clocked process - you'll end up with a single cycle delay between the two signals.  The second form is better for that (but if you change "your logic here" you'll have to remember to change both...)

Comment: The way we usually do this is by putting the `DBG_FIFO_OUT <= (your logic here);` inside of the clocked process and `DOUT <= DBG_FIFO_OUT;` outside of it (along with all the other outputs that need the same treatment)

Answer (score 2):

Use BUFFER instead of out.  Then you can read without the intermediate signal used in Charles' solution.

Comment: I would not recommend that. Most guidelines recommend that the buffers are not uses. Instead use a local signal that can be read both by the debug and regular port.

Answer (score 2):

You have good answers already for older tools - but if you use some tool which supports VHDL-2008, you are allowed to read output ports directly.  You may need to enable this with a command line option.

If your tools don't support it, whinge at the supplier until they do!